# VideoSink.OnSample to MP4 - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, mp4

I'm developping a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application based on Camera raw stream.
I need to make video samples before sending it to a distant server.

I've implemented a custom VideoSink class that overrides the 4 methods :

- OnCaptureStarted
- OnCaptureStopped
- OnFormatChange
- OnSample

I focused on the OnSample method, which give me the time of the sample, the frame duration and the sample data as a bytes array.

I'm recording from CaptureSource using this VideoFormat :

```
_video_capture_device.DesiredFormat = new videoFormat(PixelFormatType.Format8bppGrayscale, 640, 480, 30);
```

I get successfully the sample data as bytes array, but I can't find any way to encode it into a MP4 file.
I've also tested using FileSink class, but it doesn't permit to access to raw data.

Did someone already get this problem or maybe have an issue ?

Thanks !
McSime